# Find white space in a string back from an index position

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, substr

Lets say I have a string, but the text could be anything!

> This is a test case

The 'boundary' is the count after a space, this means the charIndex =

(0) This 
(5) is 
(8) a 
(10) test 
(15) case

The above means from (0) to (5) the word equals 'this '.

If I wanted to know the word just used, I would need to `substr` start at `charIndex` and look backwards until `indexOf(' ')`

Example:  If I wanted to find the word just used at charIndex (10) how would I instruct javascript to look backwards until the next space and give me the word "a ".

Is it possible to do this, with as little process time, using Javascript, or JQuery?

**UPDATE**

Instead of looking after the word and going back, I decided to achieve what I needed, I split the words and used each charIndex as a count.  Code follows:

```
var u = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
var words = element.innerHTML.split(' ');
var a = 0;
 u.text = element.innerHTML;
 u.lang = 'en-UK';
 u.rate = 0.7;
 u.onboundary = function(event) {
 console.log(words);
 element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(words[a], '<strong>' + words[a] + '</strong>');
  a++;       
  }
```

But as this is not the questions answer, still the best answer to reverse search a string is that which is marked correct, although it still needs some work depending on the string structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not clear about exact question but you can use a combination of lastindexof, indexof and substr in your case or write your own stuff.

**Note**: No error handling etc. is being done. Please do that.

```
var stringToBeParsed="This is a test case"
i = stringToBeParsed.lastIndexOf(" ",8);
j = stringToBeParsed.indexOf(" ",i+1);

document.getElementById('output').innerText = stringToBeParsed.substr(i,j-i);
```

Custom

```
function parseBackward(stringToBeParsed, indexOfSpace){
    var output = '';
    for (var i = indexOfSpace-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(stringToBeParsed.charAt(i) == ' '){
            break;
        }
        output = stringToBeParsed.charAt(i) + output;
    }    
    document.getElementById('output').innerText = output;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the above, I have put this into JSFiddle, but its showing nothing.  But it is speaking it ?  http://jsfiddle.net/mrAddy/t9k8xtkt/2/

Comment: created a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/t9k8xtkt/4/ Your speech stuff counts character but array is 0 indexed. Hence just changed few things. This is not a complete implementation and you should customize it for your need. I do  not know your specific requirement and would suggest you to play around with this and implement it further.

Comment: Thank you, I need it so I can make each word spoken bold, which is the end goal.  Once I have a word, I can then replace the closet match with a **bold word** to help children learn to read.   I shall have a play as it's missing the last work, and the first letter of the first word.  Otherwise its much better than I have managed so far :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you can use lastIndexOf:

```
var TC="This is a test case"
TC.lastIndexOf(" ",10)
```

This will return 9, using lastIndexOf(string,position) searches backwards.

EDIT:
If you need the word:

```
var TC="This is a test case"
TC.substr(TC.lastIndexOf(' ',10)+1,TC.length - TC.indexOf(' ',10));
```

So you use substr. First search backwards from position 10 space (and sum 1 to get on the beginning of letter) to start the substr. As second parameter y get the next occurrence and substract to length.

EDIT2:

Ok this functions works is supposed to work in less than milisecond:

```
function getWord(phrase,position){
  var last = phrase.indexOf(' ',position);
  var more=0
  if (last == -1){
    more = phrase.length;
  } else { more = phrase.indexOf(' ',position);}
  var word = phrase.substring(phrase.lastIndexOf(' ',position)+1,more);
  return(word);
}
```

In this plunkr http://plnkr.co/wfeitWvSvoLzqIknKFyg you can check how it takes less than a milisecond to work. And if you open a console you will see how it take the word at position specified.

Comment: That does not seem to work, as I need the word, rather than the number, and i would assume I need the second white space back, as there is always a space after the word.  Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mrAddy/t9k8xtkt/1/

Comment: Ok, take a look at the edited answer, hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, that is not working either.  I think its important to know, even though in my example, it shows the charIndex, when the speech is in progress is does not know the charIndex until its just said it.  Which is why I need an efficient way, as I need the word before it starts the next. milliseconds.

Comment: You're right @AndrewWalker previously I did not test it too much. On the plunkr example you can see how it returns you the word and how it takes less than a millisecond to perform.